# Как присвоить буквам вес независимо от регистра?

Tags: python

> На вход программе (как вариант, из входного файла text.dat) подаётся текст на английском языке. Ввод этих символов заканчивается точкой (другие символы, отличные от «.» во входных данных отсутствуют; в программе на языке Бейсик символы можно вводить по одному в строке, пока не будет введена точка). Требуется написать как можно более эффективную программу (укажите используемую версию языка программирования, например, Borland Pascal 7.0), которая будет определять и выводить на экран, какая английская буква встречается во входной последовательности чаще всего и сколько именно раз. Строчные и прописные буквы при этом не различаются. Если таких букв несколько, то программа должна выводить на экран ту из них, которая стоит по алфавиту раньше.
>   Например, пусть файл содержит следующую информацию:
>   **It is not a simple task. Yes!**
>   Тогда чаще всего встречаются буквы **I, S, T**. (слово Yes в подсчете не участвует, так как расположено после точки). Следовательно, в данном случае, программа должна вывести
>   **I 3**.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы в полученной строке  каждой букве  соответствовал определенный вес (Независимо от большой или маленькой буквы). Я пробовал реализовать через функцию `ord() - 96` (чтобы у маленьких букв был вес: 1,2....т.д), но у больших букв вес меньше и получается коряво

Comment: Приведите все буквы к одному регистру, а дальше действуйте как и планировали

Comment: *другие символы, отличные от «.» во входных данных отсутствуют* Вообще-то эта фраза означает, что во входных данных присутствуют исключительно точки...

Comment: Ну заводите массив, заполняете его, для каждой буквы инкрементируя (или прибавляя вес, если веса различны) элемент массива, индекс которого равен коду очередного символа. Встретив точку, перебираете массив, запоминая текущий максимум и его индекс, после перебора выводите символ с кодом, равным запомненному индексу.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Итог работы программы-то какой должен быть? Просто посчитать буквы можно как-нибудь так.

```
import operator

some_text = "It is not a simple task. Yes!"

#Приводим все в один регистр
some_text = some_text.lower()

#Берем все символы до точки
target_text = some_text.split('.')[0].replace(' ', '')



#считаем сколько раз повторяется каждый символ
result = {l: target_text.count(l) for l in set(target_text)}

#Список букв в порядке возрастаания повторяемости
sorted_result = sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))


#словарь букв только с самой высокой встречаемостью
max_result = {k: v for k,v in result.items() if v == sorted_result[-1][1]}

#Выбираем букву, которая будет первой по алфавиту из букв с макс. результатом
sorted_max_result = sorted(max_result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

print('Самая частотная буква - {}. Она встречается {} раз.'.format(sorted_max_result[0][0], sorted_max_result[0][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете привести символы к нижнему регистру, после чего просто сравнивать их.

Возможно, это Вам поможет:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase                # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


d = {}                                            # Частотный словарь букв
max_s = ['z', 0]                                  # Начальный максимум: z, встречается 0 раз

with open('text.dat') as f:
    raw_text = f.read().strip().lower()           # Читаем текст, удаляем лишние символы, приводим к нижнему регистру
    text = raw_text[:raw_text.find('.')]          # Отрезаем лишний текст после точки

    for x in ascii_lowercase:
        count = text.count(x)
        d[x] = count

        if count > max_s[1]:                      # Если встречается чаще текущего максимума:
            max_s = [x, count]
        elif count == max_s[1] and x < max_s[0]:  # Если встречается как максимум, но в алфавите раньше:
            max_s = [x, count]

print(*max_s)
```

*text.dat:*

```html
It is not a simple task. Yes!
```

*stdout:*

```html
i 3
```